# How to rename many classes and modules in a Django project

Tags: python, django, refactoring

I am refactoring a Django project with thousands of lines of code and dozens of source files. I need to rename many classes and modules. I am looking for a quicker and more reliable alternative to a manual search-and-replace. Something like what Java and C# IDEs let me do. I have tried Python Tools for Visual Studio and Pycharm, which have "rename" functionality for variables and classes, but they only rename within one source file, not across the whole project. Any other options?

Comment: Yes, you can use `pydev` on eclipse

Comment: PyCharm does allow you to do a rename across the whole project. Highlight the class name, right click, Refacor, Rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @infrared has noted in the comments, [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is a right tool for the job. It has a lot of refactoring tools, clever [renaming](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/rename-refactorings.html) is one of them.